# How do I render an API in React with a dynamic URL?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/?participants=2");
  const [rl, setrl] = useState("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/?participants=4");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json));
  }, [url]);

  console.log(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(rl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json));
  }, [rl]);
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>love</h1>
      <div>
        <div>
          {rl && rl.activity}
        </div>
        <button onClick={()=> setUrl("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/?participants=4")}>Get 4 participants</button>
        <button onClick={()=> setrl("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/?participants=2")}>Get 2 particiapant</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I need to show four and two participants from that API on the screen when I type the button, but it doesn’t show up. How do I recall them? I get the only in the console log, not on the page.

Comment: Are you getting any error ? What's the expected behavior ?

Comment: I want when I click the button that the API shows on my page, Im doing something wrong

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit regarding the API? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to display the result on your page:

```
<div>
     {data && (<span>data.activity</span>)}
</div>
```

Also, you can simplify your code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [participants, setParticipants] = useState(2);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/?participants=" + participants)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json));
  }, [participants]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>love</h1>
      <div>
        <div>
          {data && (<span>{data.activity}</span>)}
        </div>
        <button onClick={()=> setParticipants(4)}>Get 4 participants</button>
        <button onClick={()=> setParticipants(2)}>Get 2 particiapant</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So you have this result:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to make it so it loads new activities everytime you click the participants cuz it doesnt show more than 1 time I want it to load new info every time I click. Thanks for so far

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, my code was missing the {} around  data.activity. I will edit the answer with this line change:
<div>{data && <span>{data.activity}</span>}</div>

Comment: Do you know how I can make it to load new activity every time I click on the button because it does change only when u shift from one button to another?

Comment: you want to display all the activities after button press ? Like one line by activity ? I dont really understand what you want

Comment: return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Activity app</h1>
    <div>
    <div>
      {data && (<div>Activity:{data.activity}</div>)}   
      {data && (<div>Type:{data.type}</div>)}   
      {data && (<div>participants:{data.participants}</div>)}   
    </div>
      <button onClick={()=> setParticipants(4)}>Get 4 participants</button>
      <button onClick={()=> setParticipants(2)}>Get 2 participants</button>
      
      </div>

  </div>
);   I want one button that returns 4 and one 2 but everytime you press the button also one button that returns random number of participants